# Qu'est-ce qui change dans une phrase interrogative quand on place le mot interrogatif « pourquoi » en tête de la phrase ou après le verbe ?

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, interrogative, pronoms-interrogatifs

Est-ce toutes les phrases suivantes sont correctes ? (en langue familière et/ou soignée)

1. Les avions ne partent pas le dimanche ? (intonation, les mots dans l'ordre normal)
2. Pourquoi les avions ne partent pas le dimanche ? (mot interrogatif en tête de la phrase, et le reste des mots dans l'ordre normal)
3. Pourquoi est-ce que les avions ne partent pas le dimanche ? (construction avec « est-ce que »)
4. Les avions ne partent pas le dimanche pourquoi ? (l'ordre normal avec le mot interrogatif à la fin de la phrase)
5. Pourquoi les avions ne partent-ils pas le dimanche? (inversion complexe)

Comment: La première est familière, et usuelle. Les autres sont tout à faits correctes, la cinquième a un style soutenu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tes phrases se disent toutes sauf la 4<sup>e</sup>. La structure de la phrase ne fonctionne tout simplement pas.

Pour la première phrase, les réponses que tu obtiendras seront oui ou non. 
Pour les autres tu auras une explication.

---

### Edit

Effectivement, dans la 4<sup>e</sup> phrase, on peut ajouter une virgule avant le **pourquoi** et la phrase aura du sens.

Comment: +1 Would beginning #4 with "Et" and ending it with strong question/answer-begging intonation/inflection on the "pourquoi" help make it work, at least a little in informal speech?

Comment: L'ajout d'une virgule suffit: « Les avions ne partent pas le dimanche, pourquoi ? »